# Changing the value of a variable in one component by accessing it from another

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component in angular that is located in the `app.component.html` (the FAQ component). This sits side-by side with my Router Outlet like so:

```
<div class="site-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-callback></app-callback>
  <app-faq></app-faq>
</div>
```

One of the routes is .../question which is a question component. When a question is answered is this component (with a button click) I would like to change a value of a variable in the FAQ component.

```
answerQuestion(id: string) {
    // Answer question coding...
    faq.faqDisplay = false;
  }
```

This will change the declared variable in the FAQ component to false

```
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {
  faqDisplay = true;
}
```

I thought at first the best way to do this might be `@Input()` or `@Output()` but since these components are side-by-side and not parent and child or visa versa I think that's why I can't get that approach to work.

I can find lots of articles on passing data from parent to child etc but can't see to find anything for side-by-side communication - Is there a way to do this or maybe a work around?

Comment: Check out https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you have to do so is to use `rxjs`. Create an `Injectable` in which you'll have a `Subject` like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class YourService {

    public $faqHasChanged = new Subject<void>();

}
```

In the component you answer the question, send an event like this:

```
@Component
export class YourSenderComponent {

    constructor(
        private service: YourService,
    ) {}

    answerQuestion(id: string) {
        // Answer question coding...
        faq.faqDisplay = false;
        this.service.$faqHasChanged.next();
    }

}
```

In the component where you want to receive the information that the FAQ has changed, do like this:

```
@Component
export class YourReceiverComponent implements OnInit {

    faqDisplay = true;

    constructor(
        private service: YourService,
    ) {}

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.service.$faqHasChanged.subscribe(() => {
            this.faqDisplay = false;
        });
    }

}
```

This way, you can also receive this update anywhere you wish in you application and you are able to update the interface as you wish.

[Read more about rxjs here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) so you can improve it as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple different ways to communicate between sibling components in Angular,

Using a shared service between components and using rxjs by opening a stream `Subject`:

```
export class sharedService{
  private faqDisplay= new Subject<boolean>(); // source
  faqDisplay$ = this.faqDisplay.asObservable(); // stream
}
```

```
@Component
export class sibling1{

    constructor(
        private service: sharedService,
    ) {}

    answerQuestion(id: string) {
        // Answer question coding...
        faq.faqDisplay = false;
        this.service.faqDisplay.next(faq.faqDisplay);
    }

}
```

```
@Component
export class sibling2{

faqDisplay: boolean;

    constructor(
        private service: sharedService,
    ) {}

      public ngOnInit() {
        this.service.faqDisplay$.subscribe((value) => {
            this.faqDisplay = value;
        });
    }
}
```